# Apply a weighted average function to a dataframe without grouping it, as if it was a single group

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want to apply a function that computes something similar to a weighted average absolute deviation of **all** the elements of my data frame.

I already have a solution for it, but it seems quirky to me because I have to use groupby with a lambda function that always returns the same value:

```
def mdft(group):
    d = np.abs(my_target - group['column1'])
    w = group['weight_column']
    return (d * w).sum() / w.sum()
df.groupby(lambda x: True).apply(mdft)
```

If I don't use groupby, pandas would apply this function to every row of the dataframe, which is not my goal.

Is it possible to do the same without the groupby?

Comment: Is there a reason `mdft(df)` doesn't work?  It looks like it should.

Comment: `mdft(df)` works fine for me.  It would be good to have sample data here for clarity on what the question really is and what's not working.

Comment: Thank you @TheBlackCat and JohnE. You are right, it was not clear enough that I already have a solution. The problem is that this solution is not elegant and probably also not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_target = 25
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': np.random.normal(25, 3, 20),
                   'weight_column': np.random.random_integers(1, 10, 20)})

df
Out[4]: 
      column1  weight_column
0   23.147356              6
1   24.361162              5
2   25.665186              4
3   20.059039              1
4   28.573390              5
5   26.543743              1
6   23.177928              2
# etc.
```

Okay, so in your post when you say "If I don't use groupby, pandas would apply this function to every row of the dataframe", that's not necessarily true. You should try to read up on the way operations on `numpy` arrays are "vectorized". So, like people have pointed out in the comments, your function works fine without having to do the groupby:

```
mdft(df)
Out[9]: 1.9429828309434094
```

That said, you could have avoided writing the function in the first place because `numpy` can do weighted means for you:

```
np.average(np.abs(my_target - df['column1']), weights=df['weight_column'])
Out[8]: 1.9429828309434098
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!